# Difference between ''to say something without thinking'' and ''to say something inadvertently''

Tags: meaning, expressions, differences

Do the two have any differences and do both mean to say something unintentionally?

Answer (score 1):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/inadvertently) gives the default (most common) sense:

> **inadvertently** adverb
>
> - in a way that is not intentional

But [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inadvertent) adds a second sense (for the adjective; the adverbial sense follows):

> **inadvertent** adjective ...
>
> ... 2: not focusing the mind on a matter : *inattentive*

The second sense here is obviously largely synonymous to 'without thinking', though both phrasings are usually used when a person says a certain thing unguardedly rather than when referring to a complete airhead.

The default sense *might* be considered to be synonymous here, but people usually say what they intended to say a split second before; here, it would be the ramifications that were unintended.

I'd always use 'without thinking' here, unless I let out a secret I wasn't aware *was* a secret.

Answer (score 0):

*Inadvertent* means the same as *unintentional*. You can't exactly speak unintentionally in the same way that you can knock over a lamp unintentionally, so in effect to speak *without thinking* is the same thing.

Comment: does ''to say something without thinking'' still mean to say something unintentionally?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in my opinion, and its illustrated by these two examples:

To say something without thinking...

A man is walking down a busy street in a crime ridden part of the city and talking on his phone.

> "Hey Bill, yeah I'm carrying the 5000 cash in my bag and I'll be there
>   in ten minutes."

He didn't think about the consequences of saying what he did.

To say something inadvertently...

> Donald: "I hate paying tax. Last year I didn't pay any tax at all and
>   it felt great."

Donald has inadvertently admitted that last year he either didn't have a job or he ran a business that didn't make any profit.